# Piping Powershell multiple functions together

Tags: windows, function, powershell, pipe

I have this going on

```
Function A($data){
#Function accepts $data which is Get-Content of a file
#Function does some stuff and then return 
#Function return data as String
}

Function B($data){
#This Function takes data given from Function A, manipulate it and return custom object
}

$Function C ($data1, $data2){
#This function Takes 2 custom objects created from Function B and prints out some data
}

#For this is to work i need to do this for example:
$file = 'c:\test.txt'

$data1 = A (Get-Content $file1)
$data1 = B ($data1)

#Same thing for data2 and then use function C:

C -data1 $data2 -data2 data2
```

though this works, I would like to use Piping, i must be using it wrong

```
Get-Content $file1 | A | B
```

Would give me errors obviously.
can someone help me pipe this?

Comment: Definitely doing it wrong. Should read more, like [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-combine-multiple-commands-for-ease-of-use/) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7)

Comment: PLEASE read the help on advanced functions. you need to carefully structure your funcs to work in the pipeline. there are MANY articles on the subject ... [*grin*]

Comment: What did you search for? This is a very common thing throughout PowerShell. --- ['powershell functions valuefromp[ipline'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20functions%20valuefromp%5Bipline&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20functions%20valuefromp%5Bipline&sc=1-38&sk=&cvid=25E54A39B0AD4A3CA774C99E42B7853D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continued from my comment. For Example:

> [Building PowerShell Functions That Support the Pipeline](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/05/20/functions-that-support-the-pipeline.aspx)
>
> ValueFromPipeline Let's start off with a function to perform some
> tests.

```
#region Test Function 

Function Test-Object  
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param 
    (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][int[]]$Integer
    )

    Process  
    {
        $PSItem
    }
}

#endregion Test Function
```